# How can I change the period for Flowable.interval

Tags: rx-java2

Is there a way to change the Flowable.interval period at runtime?

```
    LOGGER.info("Start generating bullshit for 7 seconds:");

    Flowable.interval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .map(tick -> random.nextInt(100))
        .subscribe(tick -> LOGGER.info("tick = " + tick));
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(7);

    LOGGER.info("Change interval to 2 seconds:");
```

Comment: What about disposing the subscription and use a new one from a different `Flowable` with a different interval setting?

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround, but the best way would be to create a new operator.

## How does this solution work?

You have a trigger source, which will provide values, when to start start a new interval. The source is switchMapped with an interval as inner-stream. The inner-stream takes an input value for the upstream source for setting the new interval time.

### switchMap

When the source emits a time (Long), the switchMap lambda is invoked and the returned Flowable will be subscribed to immediately. When a new value arrives at the switchMap, the inner subscribed Flowable interval will be unsubscribed from and the lambda will be invoked once again. The returned Inverval-Flowable will be re-subscribed.

This means, that on each emit from the source, a new Inveral is created.

### How does it behave?

When the inveral is subscribed to and is about to emit a new value and a new value is emitted from the source, the inner-stream (inverval) is unsubscribed from. Therefore the value is not emitted anymore. The new Interval-Flowable is subscribed to and will emit a value to it's configuration.

## Solution

```
lateinit var scheduler: TestScheduler

@Before
fun init() {
    scheduler = TestScheduler()
}

@Test
fun `62232235`() {
    val trigger = PublishSubject.create<Long>()

    val switchMap = trigger.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
        // make sure, that a value is emitted from upstream, in order to make sure, that at least one interval emits values, when the upstream-sources does not provide a seed value.
        .startWith(3)
        .switchMap {
            Flowable.interval(it, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler)
                .map { tick: Long? ->
                    tick
                }
        }

    val test = switchMap.test()

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    test.assertValues(0, 1, 2)

    // send new onNext value at absolute time 10
    trigger.onNext(10)

    // the inner stream is unsubscribed and a new stream with inverval(10) is subscribed to. Therefore the first vale will be emitted at 20 (current: 10 + 10 configured)
    scheduler.advanceTimeTo(21, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    // if the switch did not happen, there would be 7 values
    test.assertValues(0, 1, 2, 0)
}
```